# Differences between apt-get, Synaptic and pip

Tags: apt, package-management, synaptic, pip

I'm only beginning to manage my own system in any sort of self-aware sense. Sometimes when I install Python packages, I use pip, sometimes apt-get and sometimes Synaptic. It generally depends on instructions I happen to be following or if I just see something that looks interesting.

Do I have to worry about these three different managers conflicting with each other? For instance, I'm fairly certain that Synaptic is just a gui for apt-get, so those two methods should never cause problems for each other. But what about pip? If I install something with pip, will apt-get & Synaptic know that package is there? Or, vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

The are all front ends for apt

https://wiki.debian.org/Apt

apt-get is a command line tool, synaptic is a nice tool but somewhat depreciated by software center.

I am not familiar with pip.

See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware

As far as I know you can use apt, apt-get, aptitude, synaptic, software center, etc without any problems.